# Laravel hasMany through belongsTo relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many-through

Is it possible to retrieve a `hasMany` relationship of the parent model via a `belongsTo` relationship of the sibling model. I have the following `Models`:

**Car**

```php
public function wheels() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Wheel');
}

public function seats() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Seat');
}
```

**Wheel**

```php
// @property int|null $car_id Type: int(10) unsigned, Extra: , Default: null, Key: MUL

public function car() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Car');
}
```

**Seat**

```php
// @property int|null $car_id Type: int(10) unsigned, Extra: , Default: null, Key: MUL

public function car() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Car');
}
```

What I would like to do is retrieve the Car's Wheels given a Seat (`$seat->wheels`):

**Seat**

```php
public function car() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Car');
}

public function wheels() {
  // Works
  // return $this->car->wheels;

  // What I would like to do, but doesn't work
  return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Wheel', 'App\Models\Car');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `HasManyThrough` is a combination of two `HasMany` relationships.

In your case, you have to switch the first foreign and local key:

```php
public function wheels() {
  return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Wheel', 'App\Models\Car', 'id', null, 'car_id');
}
```

There is an issue with column overriding that will be fixed in Laravel 5.8: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/25812

In the meantime, you can use a `BelongsToMany` relationship:

```php
public function wheels() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Wheel::class, 'cars', 'id', 'id', 'car_id', 'car_id');
}
```

Comment: This does return the `wheels` however, the `id` or each `wheel` is set to the `id` of the `car`. How can I have the `wheel` instance maintain its own Id?